# Infinite for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

No idea what I'm doing wrong here. I just need to know how many times "step" can increment until it reaches 1 -- maybe I'm overcomplicating things... I'm fairly new to programming, and I haven't done any for about a year. I don't know if this is relevant but I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 with what I believe is C11 (*very* new to this language so I have no idea of the version history).

Anyway, the following throws me into an infinite loop with 100% CPU utilisation and energy impact:

```
int range = 0;
double step = 0.12;

for(int i = step; i <= 1; i += step)
{
    range++;
}
```

"step" is only equal to 0.12 for the purposes of this example; normally it would be user-created input.

Help? :(

Comment: Hint: what is `(int)0.12`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
int range = 0;
double step = 0.12;

for (double d = step; d <= 1.0; d += step) {
    range++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a floating-point number to an `int` and get the result you expect, which is what you're doing in `int i=step`.  Very likely, you will get zero for `i`. Then, when you increment by `step`, you will get zero again, which explains the infinite loop.